# React Native ScrollView doesn't work on Android device

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
...
return (
    <>
      <View className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center mb-3">
        <Text className="text-lg font-title-600">Popular</Text>
        <Text className="text-blue font-title-500">See all</Text>
      </View>
      <ScrollView 
                horizontal={true}
                contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, columnGap: 10 }}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <ImageComponent source={{ uri: imageURLs[0]?.url }} text="Alley Palace" rating="4.1" />
        <ImageComponent source={{ uri: imageURLs[1]?.url }} text="Coeurdes Alpes" rating="4.5" />
                <ImageComponent source={{ uri: imageURLs[2]?.url }} text="Niagara falls" rating="4.8" />
      </ScrollView>
            <View className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center mt-6">
        <Text className="text-lg font-title-600">Recommended</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
```

I am using ScrollView in horizontal mode but when I am trying to scroll it nothing happened. Please don't pay attention to "className", I am using TailwindCSS plugin in React Native to define styles.

I tried to use FlatList instead of ScrollView but it didn't work too and it's not suitable for me too. Replacing 'flex' by 'flexGrow' doesn't work too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.